# $\{(\forall(x))P(x) \implies(\forall(x))Q(x)\} \implies (\forall(x))(P(x) \implies Q(x))$

Tags: predicate-logic

$(\forall(x))(P(x) \implies Q(x)) \implies \{(\forall(x))P(x) \implies (\forall(x))Q(x) \}$ why this is not valid and how the converse of this is valid?

Comment: Do you personally believe this is valid? What have you considered about the question?

Comment: Erm you got the order wrong in the question (but not in the title).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Consider the statements $x$ is divisible by $4$ and $x$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint it made sense now .I took p(x) has x is employed and q(x) has x is happy that caused the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply DRF